# HTML5 Server-Sent-Events not working on Firefox6+ browsers?

Tags: events

This is my ASP.NET for server sent events.

```
Response.ContentType = "text/event-stream";
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
//repeat loop
while (true) {
int LastEventId = Request.Headers.Get("Last-Event-ID") != null ?       
Int32.Parse(Request.Headers.Get("Last-Event-ID")) : -1;
int MessageCount =    UserManager.GetMessageCount(UserManager.GetUserDetails(Page.User.Identity.Name).UserId);
if (LastEventId != MessageCount)
{
    Response.Write(string.Format("retry: 5000\nid: {0}\ndata: {0}\n\n", MessageCount));
    Response.Flush();
}
else
{
    Response.Write(string.Format("retry: 5000\nid: {0}\ndata: \n\n", MessageCount));
    Response.Flush();
}
    if (Response.IsClientConnected == false)
{
    break;
}
    Response.Close();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

Firefox browser does not reconnect after two times. The same code is working on Google      Chrome. Can any one help me out with this?

Comment: Are the `<br/>` in your code or was that an attempt at formatting the question?

Comment: sorry that was attempt in formatting the question. breaks are not there in my code.

Comment: I am using FF 15 and it does not work here too :| (while in chromium it does work)

Comment: Hi Francesco Did you get answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove spaces after colons. Seems that Firefox parser is very sensitive to spaces and newlines. Try to change your code like this:

```
Response.Write(string.Format("retry:5000\nid:{0}\ndata:{0}\n\n", MessageCount));
```

Also defining a charset may help in some browsers:

```
Response.ContentType = "text/event-stream;charset=UTF-8";
```

Hope this helps.